Did Classical Latin authors ever incorrectly utilize an Ablative of Location for nouns that utilize the Locative Case?
I was curious if Latin authors ever also confused which nouns took the locative. For instance, did they ever accidentally say: Is in Domo est (=~ he is in the house) instead of Is domī est (he is at home)?
Thank you so much for any help.

A corpus search gives several hits for in domo.
Many of them include an attribute (e.g. privata in domo) or are parallel to other expressions (e.g. in domo, in sedibus, in aris, in focis...).
On a quick glance I see no cases of a plain in domo, but there may well be some down the list.
I invite you to take a look at the search results to get a feeling for how common this is.
You can use the same tool to study other phrases, too.
If there are instances of in domo where you would expect domi based on our Latin grammars, I would not treat it as a mistake or an accident.
Our Latin grammars are a simplified description of the language of the ancient Romans, not a definitive list of rules that they had to follow.
